# Code on SMD component with only ADJF

Tags: digital-logic

I need to know what the part number is for a 6 pin SMD component. The code on the case is ADJF. Please let me know if anyone has a datasheet or information for this device. The circuit board is an audio display MP3 player with four switches that can switch an audio signal to four external devices with auxiliary cables such as amplifiers, headphones, portable Bluetooth speakers, etc.

[image: Photo of part]

Comment: I need to know information on 'x', but I'm not going to tell you anything about what 'x' is, what it is part of, a photo of what it came from, or any context whatsoever.

Comment: Probably an [MP1470](http://www.monolithicpower.com/desktopmodules/documentmanage/api/document/getdocument?id=418) but with no other info to go on...

Comment: In case you are wondering, I just googled `sot23-6 "adjf"` making a pure guess that it is a SOT23-6 package.

Comment: http://s32.postimg.org/9dg9ftf8l/20160510_231302_1.jpg

Answer (score 3):

With the photo added, it does indeed appear to be an MP1470.

Comparing the pin functions from the [datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/pub/media/document/MP1470_r1.02.pdf) we see that the circuit does indeed seem to match.

There's a capacitor between pins 2 and 6 which match the boost capacitor in the example schematic. Pin 4 is connected to a network of resistors which seems correct. Pin 3 seems to be some form of power input with a nice filter capacitor. And then there is the big inductor in the circuit which indeed confirms it is a switching regulator circuit.